# Dual of an injective homomorphism on $\mathbb{Z}$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $f: X\to Y$ is a homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.
If we apply the $\operatorname{Hom}(-, \mathbb{Z})$ functor to the diagram $X\to Y$, then is the induced map $f^*$ necessarily injective?

Comment: If $f$ is surjective, then $f^*$ is injective, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, even with $f$ injective, $f*$ might not be injective.

Consider $X = \mathbb{Z}$, $Y = \mathbb{Z}^2$, and $f : x \mapsto (x,0)$ the canonical injection.
Take $h_1,h_2 \in \operatorname{Hom}(Y, \mathbb{Z})$ defined by $h_i (x,y) = i\cdot y$. One has $h_1\neq h_2$ but $f^*(h_1) = f^*(h_2) = 0$.

Hence $f^*$ is not injective.